# Why doesn't strace report that the parent shell fork() a child process before execve() a command?

Tags: bash, shell, fork, strace

`strace` runs a specified command until it exits.  It intercepts and records the system calls which are called by a process and the  signals  which are received by a process.

When running an external command in a bash shell, the shell first `fork()` a child process, and then `execve()` the command in the child process. So I guess that `strace` will report `fork()` or something similar such as `clone()`

But the following example shows it doesn't. Why doesn't `strace` report that the parent shell `fork()` the child process before `execve()` the command? Thanks.

```
$ strace -f time
execve("/usr/bin/time", ["time"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x84c000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efe9b2a5000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=141491, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 141491, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7efe9b282000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1840928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3949248, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7efe9acc0000
mprotect(0x7efe9ae7b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7efe9b07a000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ba000) = 0x7efe9b07a000
mmap(0x7efe9b080000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efe9b080000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efe9b281000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efe9b27f000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7efe9b27f740) = 0
mprotect(0x7efe9b07a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x602000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7efe9b2a7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7efe9b282000, 141491)          = 0
write(2, "Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] "..., 177Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]
) = 177
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Where is the shell in this example?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The bash shell where I run the command will first fork a sub process which is a copy of itself, and then the sub process will execve the specified command `time`.

Comment: The subprocess will exec the specified command `strace`.

Comment: Then the output of `strace` starts at the beginning of *its* child. If you want to trace a shell, you have to strace the shell. `strace -f -e trace=process sh -c '/usr/bin/time ; echo'` or something.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks. I see.  Why do you add `echo` after `/usr/bin/time`?

Comment: Otherwise the shell may just decide to exec itself out of existence if it's not going to have to do anything more after running the program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ strace -f time
execve("/usr/bin/time", ["time"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x84c000
...
```

Strace directly invokes the program to be traced. It doesn't use the shell to run child commands, unless the child command *is* a shell invocation. The approximate sequence of events here is as follows:

1. The shell executes `strace` with arguments "strace", "-f", "time".
2. Strace starts up, parses its command line, and eventually forks.
3. The original (parent) strace process begins tracing the child strace process.
4. The child strace process executes `/usr/bin/time` with the argument "time".
5. The time program starts up.

After step 1, the original shell process is idle, waiting for strace to exit. It's not actively doing anything. And even if it were doing something, it's not being traced by strace, so its activity wouldn't appear in the strace output.

Comment: Thanks. Before tracing begins, are there two calls to `fork()` (first one is by the parent shell to run `strace`, and the second one is to run `time`)? Or is there only one call to `fork()`?

Answer (score 4):

The `fork` in question is part of the mechanism which launches `strace`; it has concluded by the time tracing begins.

Comment: Thanks. Before tracing begins, are there two calls to `fork()` (first one is by the parent shell to run `strace`, and the second one is to run `time`)? Or is there only one call to `fork()`?